# TextInput OnChange in React native

Tags: react-native

Please help me. I have a `TextInput`, my problem is when I type the numeric value, that value going to multiply with some number. When I type `1000`, this will get saved to state as `1000`, but it saves to `store` as `100`. The results differ.

```
 <TextInput
  onChangeText={this.handle_bill_Amount}
  style={styles.input} 
  placeholder="Amount"
  value={this.state.Amount}
  keyboardType = 'numeric'
  enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
  placeholderTextColor = "#824242"
  underlineColorAndroid="transparent">
 </TextInput>


  handle_bill_Amount = Amount => {
  this.setState({ Amount})
  let billamt = this.state.Amount;
  console.log(billamt);
  }

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    Amount: '',
    }
    this.handle_bill_Amount = this.handle_bill_Amount.bind(this);
}
```

Guys help me please!

Comment: Check this out https://snack.expo.io/rJlNjP94- . If you have more concerns, let me know

Answer (score 1):

**this.setState** is async in nature, hence non-deterministic in the next statement. So, when you are logging the value, state might not yet have the updated value.
So for deterministic behavior, it is advised that you use the second argument, which is a callback, to get the correct state. It is invoked when `setState` is executed.

```
this.setState({Amount}, () => console.log(this.state.Amount))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think results are not different, it's just your `console.log` which confuses you. It will print out `100` instead of `1000` because your are doing console log inside the function which is setting the new state. Try to do it somewhere else, e.g. in `componentWillReceiveProps`, or `componentWillUpdate` and you'll see it's ok.

Hope this helps.